# fparsec to parse sequence of string

Tags: f#, fparsec

I have an user input text like "abc,def,ghi". I want to parse it to get list of string as ["abc", "def"].

I tried

```
let str : Parser<_> = many1Chars (noneOf ",")
let listParser : Parser<_> = many (str);;
```

but it always give me the first item only ["abc"]. "Def" and others are not coming in result list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parsing up to the first comma, but not parsing the comma itself.

To parse a list of things separated by other things, use [`sepBy`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html):

```
let comma = pstring ","
let listParser = sepBy str comma
```

If you need to parse "at least one", use `sepBy1` instead.