# FParsec list of string between special char

Tags: f#, fparsec

When trying to parse `{asdc,456,ghji,abc}` and I run

```
run specialListParser "{asdc,456,ghji,abc}"
```

the parser fails with

> The error occurred at the end of the input stream.
>   Expecting: any char not in ‘,’, ',' or '}'

I defined my parser based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625973/fparsec-to-parse-sequence-of-string):

```
let str : Parser<_> = many1Chars (noneOf ",")
let comma = pstring ","
let listParser = sepBy str comma

let specialListParser = between (pstring "{") (pstring "}") listParser
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "Not working" is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working". What error message are you getting? Try implementing the `test` function from [this section of the FParsec tutorial](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-a-single-float) and run `test specialListParser "{def,ghi,jkl}"`. What does it output?

Comment: Basically, you haven't yet provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your precise problem, and it's going to be hard to give you useful answers until you tell us more.

Comment: Now that I see what your error message was, I was able to reproduce the problem myself, and fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your `str` parser is consuming the final `}`, so that `between` never gets to see it. Change your `str` parser to be `many1Chars (noneOf ",}")` and it should work.

Alternately, `noneOf [','; '}']` would also work, and might be more explicit about your intentions.

Comment: @rumnn thanks for reply. your suggestion solves the successful scenario, but its not giving for negative scenarios (where parser should have thrown error).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "its not giving for negative scenarios". Could you rephrase that? Or give an example of an input where the parser *should* have thrown an error, but didn't?

Comment: @rumn please ignore my previous comment.